# can't start namenode after running start-dfs.sh (hadoop 2.7.1)

Tags: java, bash, hadoop, configuration

When trying to construct the local pseudo Hadoop environment, I have this errors when i'm trying to start my namenode with `start-dfs.sh`

```
"Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf"
```

My java version is as shown below

```
java version "1.7.0_85"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)
```

I have also changed the line in my `hadoop-env.sh`, under `/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

For etc/hadoop/core-site.xml, i put

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

For etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml, i put

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I have also changed my /home/hduser/.bashrc file, add lines as below:(all paths are correct)

```
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export HADOOP_PREFIX =/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=${HADOOP_PREFIX}/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=${HADOOP_PREFIX}/lib/native"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
#HADOOP VARIABLES END
```

When type in start-dfs.sh, only datanode shows, and when start-all.sh. Nodemanager and datanode shows.

```
6098 NodeManager
5691 DataNode
6267 Jps
```

Nothing shows from the http://localhost:*****/

Comment: Check your `JAVA_HOME` path and try `./hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode ` to start namenode and `jps` command to check

Answer (score 2):

Format your namenode first by using this command `hadoop namenode -format` and then try to execute this from your terminal `./hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode`. 
`jps` command to check.

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration> 
  <property> 
    <name>fs.default.name</name> 
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> 
  </property> 
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration> 
 <property> 
  <name>dfs.replication</name> 
  <value>1</value> 
 </property> 
 <property> 
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
  <value>/path/hadoop/namenode</value> 
 </property> 
 <property> 
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
  <value>/path/hadoop/datanode</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: I believe the java path was correct, just had a quick chek of the start namenode by it self, and also had an error

Comment: @Max_Guo   have you formatted namenode before? format using this command `hadoop namenode -format`

Comment: @Max_Guo       any luck?